# BigDecimal values wants set a new scale

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal value, for example

```
BigDecimal bdVal = new BigDecimal("3.141592653");
```

I really want this value printed to be

```
dbVal: 3.141600000
```

What should I do for that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to round the value up to four decimal places, use

```
BigDecimal rounded = bdVal.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

To print it with nine zeros, use this format:

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000000000");
String formatted = decFormat.format(rounded);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Obz7Xi)

Comment: Hi, I could get HALF_UP, but..I'm not permitted to use classes other than BigDecimal and RoundingMode, is there other way to append zeros at tail ??

Comment: You could `setScale` twice, once to 4 decimal places, and then again to nine.

Comment: @JizhouZhang See what Louis wrote above. This would do the trick without the formatter.